# What is the usual approach, should we skip .htaccess file from git repository

Tags: git, apache, .htaccess, gitignore

Should we add .htaccess file in .gitignore, how we manage this file?

Comment: Your `.htaccess` file would normally go in your `root`. It would only go in specific directories if you wanted to use it for specific actions related to that directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether you add `.htaccess` to `.gitignore` depends on whether you want the `.htaccess` file tracked in your Git repository or not. You have to decide this for yourself, noone can tell you this really.